# Windows 11 and USB sticks with multiple partitions

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive, windows-11

Has Windows 11 brought back the limitation where it only shows the first partition on USB flash drives? I have been able to use USB sticks with multiple partitions since the Windows 10 Creators Update and they all showed up in Explorer.

But Windows 11 seems to have removed this feature so it's back to showing just the first partition with no way of accessing the other partitions.

I have tried Disk Management but all the options in the right click menu for the other partitions are greyed out so can't mount any of them. I have 3 Windows 11 computers all with the same problem yet no such problem with my Windows 10 computers.

Is there any way of accessing the other partitions on USB flash drives in Windows 11 just like I could in Windows 10 since the Creators Update?

Comment: I haven't seen it reported yet but if true that's quite a regression.

Comment: Which Win 11 version are you on?

Comment: On Win 11 v22H2 build 22621.1105

Comment: Please add that (or any additional) info to the question also.